# How can I ignore SSL certificate error in Newman

Tags: postman, newman

I use the following thing in the command line

```
newman run e_api.json -e ent_env.json --reporters cli,html
```

But it shows me `unable to verify the first certificate error`

How can I ignore https/ssl certificate error?

I tried using following command, but it's not working.

```
newman run e_api.json -e ent_env.json --reporters cli,html --ignore-https_proxy
```

Comment: Give a try `newman run e_api.json -e ent_env.json --reporters cli,html --insecure`

Answer (score 29):

As per [Newman documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/#options),  there is an option `--insecure` to disable strict SSL.

```
newman run e_api.json -e ent_env.json --reporters cli,html --insecure
```

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem

it is my first command :

```
newman run "PostmanExport.json"
```

on this command I resaved this error:

```
 unable to verify the first certificate
```

I change my Command to this

```
 newman run "PostmanExport.json" --insecure
```